# Lvalue required: error in c

Tags: c, lvalue

```
if(puzzle[i][j] >= '0' && puzzle[i][j] <= '8' && puzzle[i][j] = '.')
```

I have that code and when I compile it, it gets Lvalue required error. Help. Thanks!
here is the full code. What I'm trying to do is to check the input of the user with the guidelines:
1) The input should be 0 to 8 and '.'
2) In the corners of the table( since it is a 2d array, it should be less than 3.

```
int main()
{
char puzzle[7][7];
int i;
int j;

printf("Enter your Tentaizu Puzzle:\n");

for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
  for(j = 0; j <7; j++){
    scanf("%s", &puzzle[i][j]);
    }
}
if(puzzle[i][j] >= '0' && puzzle[i][j] <= '8' && puzzle[i][j] == '.'){
    if((puzzle[0][0] <= '3' && puzzle[0][6] <= '3') || (puzzle[6][0] <='3' &&  puzzle[6][6] <= '3')){
    printf("Tentaizu Puzzle\n");
     for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        for(j = 0; j <7; j++){
                printf("%s\n", puzzle[i][j]);
            }
        }
  }
}


getch();
}
```

Comment: Please post more code, including the declaration of `puzzle`. Anyway there is error in the last condition, should be `==` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You typed `=` where you meant `==`. As a result, C is trying to assign `'.'` to the result of `puzzle[i][j] >= '0' && puzzle[i][j] <= '8' && puzzle[i][j]` -- and you can't assign a value to a (boolean, in this case) value.

Comment: @user3395969 please feel free to close the thread by selecting the tick mark.